# prevent further http calls to images

Tags: angularjs, http

I have encountered the following problem, please help me out. In an AngularJS app, I am making a $http.get request to '/abc' url. The data I receive is in the form of html. I am supposed to parse the html and get useful data out of it. Now the problem is, in the original url '/abc', there are many images of "folders".

```
<img src = "/icons/folder.gif" alt = [DIR]">
```

I am getting the response in the form of html, but after it enters the success callback, additional requests are being made to 'currentPath/icons/folder.gif'. This is happening automatically. How do I prevent these requests?

Code written in $http get

```
_commonModule.server.http($http, '/abc')
    .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
        pageData = parseHTML(response);

        console.log("hi");
    })
    .error(function(errResp) {
    });
```

parseHTML function converts the html to json data. In console, "hi" is getting printed and then I'm getting --- "GET http://unixdev:5678/icons/folder.gif 404 (Not Found)"

and finally in the parseHTML function, I am creating a dummy dom element and parsing it

```
var tempData = document.createElement('html');
tempData.innerHTML = response;
var numberOfRows = tempData.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
```

Comment: please post the code you have written with $http

Comment: tried using ng-src ?

Comment: i dont want to display the html, i just want get the html and parse it. And I want to prevent the calls made to /icons/folder.gif